# display typeahead suggestion using handlebars?

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js, typeahead

Im having trouble displaying the selected typeahead suggestion in the input field. I know I am overlooking something obvious but cannot figure it out. My code below includes return null; I have changed this to return suggestion, but since my handebar is compiled after this, I get [Object object] in the input field. Any help for displaying the selected typeahead in the field?

```
$("#q").typeahead({
    highlight: false,
    minLength:1
},
{
    display: function(suggestion) { return null },
    // limit:10,
    source: search,
    templates: {
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile(
            "<div>"+
            "{{tool_class}}, {{tool_class_2}}, {{tool_class_3}}" +
            "</div>"
        )
    }
});

// Query tools db for matching ools selected in drop-down within set boundaries 
$("#q").on("typeahead:selected", function(eventObject, suggestion, name) {
    var myLatLng;
    var parameters = {
        q: $("#q").val()
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: I figured it out. I updated the return value in display to be one of the elements in the custom handlebar template I created. I was originally trying to return the entire template, which I am still interested in doing if someone knows how?

My new code:

```
$("#q").typeahead({
    highlight: false,
    minLength:1
},
{
    display: function(suggestion) { **return suggestion.tool_class_3** },
    // limit:10,
    source: search,
    templates: {
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile(
            "<div>"+
            "{{tool_class}}, {{tool_class_2}}, {{tool_class_3}}" +
            "</div>"
        )
    }
});
```